# LVM Logical Volumes will not activate on Cloudlinux 7.8

Tags: centos, centos7, lvm, fstab, cloudlinux

Recently, after a reboot, the system landed in Emergency Mode. The cause appears to be that the system is failing to mount a few of the disks as defined in /etc/fstab. These disks are Logical Volumes.

Of the 6 Logical Volumes on the server, 3 are working ok and 3 are not starting up. All of these are on the one PV (Physical Volume), and in the same Volume Group.

Some relevant errors from `journalctl -xb` are (repeated for each of the 3 failed LVs):

```
Job dev-mapper-cloudlinuz\x2dvar.device/start timed out.
Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-cloudlinuz\x2dtmp.device
```

The `lvscan` and `lvdisplay` commands show these LVs as "NOT Available".
[View pv, vg, lv status - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLmHQ.png)

Running `lvchange -ay` on the LV  does not display an error (or any output) but the LV remains NOT Available. Similarly, running `vgchange -ay cloudlinux` displays the output: *2 logical volume(s) in volume groups "cloudlinux" now active.*
[View output from lvchange and vgchange - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnH1M.png)

Booting from a CentOS Live Disk into recovery mode mounts the Volumes with no issue and all files are present. `fsck` reports no errors on the Volumes.
[View lvscan output from recovery mode - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJi9u.png)

I also tried booting into an older Kernel from the boot screen. This did not help (LVs could not be activated).

Comment: Check `dmesg` for anything interesting or unusual.

Comment: I can't see anything useful in ```dmesg```. I have loaded the output [here](http://dev2.webbird.net.au/dmesg2.txt). Note that all Logical Volumes are on the partition xvda2.

Comment: After a second look, perhaps this line is relevant:
```[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.27.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/cloudlinux-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=cloudlinux/root rd.lvm.lv=cloudlinux/swap rd.lvm.lv=cloudlinux/usr rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8```
The three LVs mentioned here are the working ones. I have no idea where this comes from though, or what it does.

Comment: Ok, so adding the other 3 LVs to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` parameter in `/etc/default/grub`, then running `grub2-mkconfig –o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, allows the server to load normally and all LVs are connected.
Strangely other working servers do not have all LVs loading in GRUB parameters. I guess, this is sort of solved, but I would still like to know what went wrong before we put the server back into production.

Comment: You should just be able to use `rd.auto` to autodetect all storage each boot, but this adds a few seconds to the boot time.